# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none issue

Tags: spring-boot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzReB.jpg)

I am using a schema.sql and data.sql to insert data in h2 database.

each time I run the app, i need to manually run the insert command in h2 console to insert the data. I have one registartion form link in home page for "candidate". I fill data in the form and the data is added in the database. It is working fine in this case.

But I want to prepopultate the data. so I used

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none, now the data in data.sql is being prepopulated, but when I fill the data in registration form after submitting the data I am getting an error.

could not prepare statement; SQL [select employee0_.email as email1_0_0_, employee0_.first_name as first_na2_0_0_, employee0_.last_name as last_nam3_0_0_, employee0_.password as password4_0_0_, employee0_.role as role5_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.email=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

gitlab link:

https://gitlab.com/DipronilDey/Assessment

Please help.

Comment: Please, don't use linked images on SO

Comment: Check if the employee table structure you have mentioned in `schema.sql` is matching with the Employee entity class you have created

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot uses [`SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/hibernate/SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.java#L60-L71), generates "`first_name`" as column name.

You want "`firstName`", so you need set physical-naming-strategy explicitly:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

reference:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties